# PHP foreach insert statement issue with arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, loops

Hey guys, i'm currently learning php and I need to do this

```
  $connection = mysql_open();
  $likes= array();
  foreach($likes as $like)
  {

  $insert3 = "insert into ProfileInterests " .
    "values ('$id', '$like', null)";
  $result3 = @ mysql_query ($insert3, $connection)
    or showerror();

  }
  mysql_close($connection)
    or showerror();
```

For some reason this does not work =/ I don't know why. $likes is an array which was a user input. I need it to insert into the table it multiple times until all of the things in the array are in.

***EDIT*** I fixed the issue where I was closing it in my foreach loop. mysql_open is my own function btw.

Any ideas?

Comment: Backticks ("\`") are for inline code. For blocks of code, indent lines an extra four spaces, which preserves whitespace and colorizes the code. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: "this does not work" tells us almost nothing. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens (including any error messages)?

Comment: Also, the mysql extension is very out-of-date and has been supplanted twice over; instead, use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO). If you need a tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). One very important feature that PDO supports is [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements). With mysql_*, if you ever interpolate user input directly into queries, your site is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), but prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one $likes is an empty array in your example, I am assuming you fix that in the code you run.

The second is you close the MySQL connection the first the time the loop would run, which would prevent subsequent MySQL queries from running.

Comment: I did that but it still does not work now :(
have a look at main question please I am putting in the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

there's no such function as `mysql_open`

you may need `mysql_connect`

also `$likes` variable is empty. so no foreach iterations will execute.

Comment: it's my own function :P the variable is not empty I defined it earlier on.

Comment: ahhhhh I see that's 1 issue I did this $likes= array($likes);

Likes should already be an array though, but when I don't do $likes = array(); I get an error.
which is 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ____ on line 50 Notice: Undefined variable: error in ____ on line 52

Answer (score 0):

You close the connection within the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper formatted code to insert data...You can use this.

// DATABASE CONNECTION

```
$conn=mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS);
$link=mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME,$conn);
```

// function to insert data ..here **$tableName** is name of table and **$valuesArray** array of user input

```
function insertData($tableName,$valuesArray) {

        $sqlInsert="";
        $sqlValues="";

        $arrayKeys = array_keys($valuesArray);
        for($i=0;$i < count($arrayKeys);$i++)
        {
            $sqlInsert .= $arrayKeys[$i].",";
            $sqlValues .= '"'.$valuesArray[$arrayKeys[$i]].'",';
        }

        if($sqlInsert != "")
        {
            $sqlInsert = substr($sqlInsert,0,strlen($sqlInsert)-1);
            $sqlValues = substr($sqlValues,0,strlen($sqlValues)-1);
        }

        $sSql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($sqlInsert) VALUES ($sqlValues)";  
        $inser_general_result=mysql_query($sSql) or die(mysql_error());
        $lastID=mysql_insert_id();
        $_false="0";
        $_true="1";
        if(mysql_affected_rows()=='0')
        {
            return $_false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $lastID;
        }
    }
```

// End Of Function

Answer (score 0):

While many PHP newbies (*myself included*) begin working with databases from good ole' `mysql_connect/query/etc.`, I can't help suggest that you look into [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), PHP Data Objects. Depending on your prior knowledge and programming background, there may be a steeper learning curve. However, it's much more powerful, extensible, etc.; I use `PDO` in all my production code database wheelings-and-dealings now.